# How to Change Java project into a gwt web application in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, web-applications

I have an existing java Project in eclipse and I need to convert it into a GWT web project to deploy it.

I've already changed it with right click on `project > properties > google > Web toolkit` to get the GWT sdk and `right click project > properties > google > app engine` use google app engine to get app engine sdk.

The problem is that I dont have a WAR so I can't deploy it and I can't chose a directory in the settings. I could copy the WAR from an existing GWT Project but thats not really working.

Any suggestions of how can I change it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that you are using the GWT Plugin for Eclipse, just set your WAR directory to the webapp directory of your project:

[image]

If you are using v3 of the GWT Plugin for Eclipse, it might be necessary to update the project facets by clicking the GWT facet:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, sorry that isnt working when im doing this I still cant deploy the project and this change is not automatically  adding the needed xml files etc for deploying the project but thanks a lot for your help

Comment: are you using Maven?